# Conditional text-color for the DataGrid rows?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

I have a datagrid which is bound to a database table. I need to change the forecolor of a row to blue depending on there is a value in one of its columns. Is there a way I can do this? I tried IValueConverter, but I presume I can use this only for one cell at a time.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you tried this code? I assure you that this changes the forecolor of the row as a whole. Unless you are using DataGridTemplateColumns or something.

Comment: @kevev22 Even then it should work unless individual templates overrdie TextBlock.Foreground:)

Comment: Could anyone explain me in a few words, why does it affect the whole DataGridRow and turns it Foreground to Blue and not only the DataGridCell? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```xml
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```