# Changing Row Color by specific Condition WPF Datagrid

Tags: row, background-color

I have the exact same problem as this guy:

[How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

The differenence is that i use WPF. So .rows doesnt exist. 
Does anybody of you have a clue how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional text-color for the DataGrid rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259616/conditional-text-color-for-the-datagrid-rows)

Comment: i have two cells. if cell.a is bigger then cell.b i want to change the row color. this guy only wants to change it if one cell is filled

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
private void dgAnzeigeKostenstelle_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataContext)).Row.ItemArray[5]) > Convert.ToInt32(((System.Data.DataRowView)(e.Row.DataContext)).Row.ItemArray[4]))
                {
                    e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.OrangeRed);
                } 
            }
            catch
            {
            } 
        }
```