# WPF DataGrid row color change based on variable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm using data triggers to change the color of the rows in a DataGrid view component. 
the code is:

```
class QuantityToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value <= 444 ?
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
                : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
}
```

How can I replace the '444' value by a variable that has the result of some computation of the grid cell values in the button_click function?

EDIT: to make it more clear what I need: I want to change the color of the rows which have the value in one of the columns bigger than the average . As the average is computed based on the DataGrid data, I need to send it as a variable instead of the 444 constant.

EDIT2: the button code:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<ActionLog>();

        var result = engine.ReadFile("browse.csv");
        // result is now an array of ActionLog

        var actionsCnt = new int[22];

        int curAccessId =  result[1].AccessId;
        int AccessCount = 0;

        foreach (var record in result)
        {
            actionsCnt[record.ActionType]++;
            if (record.AccessId != curAccessId) { curAccessId = record.AccessId;  AccessCount++; }
        }

        quantityThreshold = AccessCount;

        List<act> myList = new List<act>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++)
            myList.Add(new act() { actionID = i, quantity = actionsCnt[i] });

        grid1.ItemsSource = myList;

        engine.WriteFile("FileOut.csv", result);
    }
```

**quantityThreshold** is the variable I want to use instead of '444'

Comment: converters also have a parameter... this object parameter argument

Answer (score 2):

Bind that computed variable to your Converter's `ConverterParameter`. See this thread on [Binding to Converter Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388326/binding-to-converter-parameter)

```
 return (int)value <= (int)parameter?
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)
                : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Comment: thank you! but I still do not get how to send '(int)parameter' from my button_click function

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue" >
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

[refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259616/conditional-text-color-for-the-datagrid-rows)

Comment: That's what is on the XAML part. But I need to change the color comparing it to a variable not a constant number on the C# side.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass parameter to converter, like this

```
...
Binding="{Binding ValueToBind, Converter={SomeConverter},ConverterParameter=YourParameteres}"
...
```

And then use it in your converter as object parameter

Comment: Thank you! but that is not what I am looking for. I need to evaluate a value on a button click and use it in the converter. I don't understand how to pass it properly to the converter.

Comment: Sorry for mega delay, but I'm out of time now.
OK, but try to focus on the point of your question.
I think, that I don't undertand what exactly you need in 100%, but I try to get you another clues.

Maybe you could use property in your button event. That property will be bindend to your row color property. And than, when you change it, bindning mechanizm automatycally change row color property. 
I hope that you get what I mean.

Comment: Thank you! I think I get your idea. As it is working on a constant and not on a variable which is evaluated during runtime makes me think that the update should be triggered on some event instead of doing it onLoad as XAML does. The point is I am not familiar with WPF and XAML interaction and binding. Now reading books on that topic. Anyway, thank you for your time and your help. Really appreciate!